# How can I make a perspective camera look like orthographic camera?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I'm using an addon that uses the camera view to imitate 2d outlines. While messing around with camera settings, I found ortho camera looks better than perspective for imitating 2d drawings. However the addon will only work if the camera is in perspective mode so it can capture it properly using geo nodes. Am I screwed into picking one or the other? Here is a visual representing my situation

[image: Visual]

The issue with the outline is that it just becomes really small when put into ortho

[image: Small outline]

Comment: Which addon are you using? If you paid for it you could probably email the author and ask them directly.

Comment: dont know if im allowed to include a link but i purchased it on gumroad and dont see an option to let me contact the seller

Comment: When you can only use a perspective camera but want to have an orthographic look, the only possibility is to have a very high focal length and move the camera far away. The further away the camera from the object, the less perspective distortion, just like taking photos in real life.